# Why is there a NULL-entry in the "Fields and Values" section of the QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, null

In the QGIS field calculator you can choose the Fields you want to add to your field calculator expression.

I wonder why there is also "NULL" listed as one option?

Choosing NULL as a value makes sense to me (for example 'field1 is null') but choosing NULL as a column identifier does not make sense to me.

Am i missing something or is this just a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. [image]
Every layer has NULL in it's 3rd field.

And it [looks like an old bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242795/qgis-expression-calculator-field-shows-null) that hasn't been resolved yet, even in QGIS3

Comment: I have a pull request ready for this soon for QGIS 3.4 so it will now be a button and no longer in the field list.

Comment: @NathanW off topic but what's the intended use for this?

Comment: Just inserts the value NULL into the expression really that is all.